# C++ Linux App Referencing C# DLL

Tags: c++, .net, linux, mono, .net-remoting

MyWinApp is a .NET 4.5.2 desktop app that exposes a .NET Remoting interface (I can't go to WCF right now, nor is .NET Core an option yet). I want to support this scenario: TheirLinuxC++App running on a Linux box controlling MyWinApp running on a Win10 PC. So the core problem seems to be: TheirLinuxC++App must reference MyWinRemotingDLL, the interface assembly which must exist on both sides of the link for .NET Remoting. I've run across references to "embedding Mono", so here's my question: If Mono is installed on the Linux box and TheirLinuxC++App compiles in libMono, will they be able to directly call methods defined in MyWinRemotingDLL from their C++ code?

Comment: "directly call methods"... depends upon what you mean by "directly", but yes..., there is call setup, the translation of data types between managed types into unmanaged typed and back, etc....  And you have to look at the managed API they will be calling, if you are returning some custom managed C# class, what is the C/C++ program going to do with that, if your api needs an List<SomeC#Class> how would the C/C++ construct that, refactoring the managed API might be required to use only base types , etc...  http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/embedding/#invoking-methods-in-the-cil-universe

Comment: Thanks @SushiHangover, great link. By "directly call" I meant not needing to develop a C++/CLI adapter DLL. Sounds like I won't. I now know it is worth me digging in deeper to see if my API creates unnecessary burdens for those clients.